# SSLSocket handshake: Socket timed out

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, amazon-web-services, sni

I'll try to give as much details as I can:

I am running Java 8u45 program on Windows m1.small AWS instances. I am trying to do something similar to:

```
SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sslSocketFactory.createSocket(socket, hostname, port, true);
sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
sslSocket.startHandshake();
```

And this bit code code works in general. But for a particular site, if the hostname is set, the startHandshake() throws an exception after about a minute saying that the socket timed out. If I do not specify the hostname (i.e. it is null), the handshake passes and no timeout occurs.

The strange thing is that before Java 8u45 the instances was using Java 7u79, and never had this issue. Moreover if I run the same code locally the handshake also passes without a problem.

I believed this to be an SNI problem but the exception thrown is a socket timeout and not an unrecognized_name, so I'm not sure why this is happening/started to happen after upgrading to Java 8.

Does anyone have any insight as to why this may be happening?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how the whole infrastructure works, but I think the socket is given by a Selenium Jetty HttpConnection's getConnection(); I believe it essentially wraps that socket to an SSLSocket

Comment: If you provide the affected URL (i.e. host and port) one can maybe have a look at it.